# how to calculate the average of an array by range 10?

Tags: python, arrays, algorithm, average

i am trying to find the average of an array by range 10 in a sorted array, for example : `[1,2,3,5,11,12,13,15,22,25,27,30]` should return `[6,17,27]`
the function is supposed to groupe the numbers by a range of 10 and make the average between 
[1,2,3,5,11] = (1+11)/2    =6

[12,13,15,22]= (12+22)/2  =17

[25,27,30] = (25+30)/2   =27

here is my code

```
def par(s):

    g = []
    i = 0
    while i <= len(s):
        y =s[i] + 10

        n = (s[i]+y)/2
        g.append(n)

        for x in s:
            if y <= x:
                i = s.index(x)
                break

    return g
```

Comment: And the problem with that code is?

Comment: First: I have no clear idea what you want this function to do. Second: What is wrong with your code? Third: Your code is not self-contained. The last one may be nitpicking, but it increases the likelihood of someone actually trying out your code if (s)he can just copy and paste it into a Python interpreter.

Comment: the function is supposed to groupe the numbers by a range of 10 and make the average

Comment: @nooby102030 See my answer below. Are the sublists in my solution grouped as you expect them to be? If not, can you edit your question to show how you want them grouped?

Comment: Are you trying to implement a moving average?

Comment: yes and groupe them in an array

Comment: Hint: When asking *how* to do something, please clearly describe *what* you're trying to do. If you can't provide a *clear, exact and unambiguous* description of what you're trying to do, it often helps to also tell us *why* you're trying to do it, so that we can fill in the holes in your description ourselves. In this case, you're given an unclear and rather strange description of *what* you want to do, and absolutely no hint of *why*; accordingly, I've voted to put your question on hold as unclear, to give you a chance to clarify it before people start tossing out random guesses as answers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
data = [1,2,3,5,11,12,13,15,22,25,27,30]

# divide it into blocks like [[a .. a+10], [b .. b+10], ...]
result = []
block  = None
for d in data:
    if block:
        if d <= hi:
            # belongs to current block
            block.append(d)
        else:
            # start a new block
            result.append(block)  # finish previous block
            block = [d]           # start new block
            lo, hi = d, d + 10    # reset endpoints for new block
    else:
        # special handling for first value encountered
        block = [d]
        lo, hi = d, d + 10
# cleanup
if block:
    result.append(block)

# result = [[1, 2, 3, 5, 11], [12, 13, 15, 22], [25, 27, 30]]

# find midpoint for each block
mid_points = [(block[0] + block[-1]) // 2 for block in result]

# mid_points = [6, 17, 27]
```

Comment: This answer deserves an upvote for the first comment line alone: `# divide it into blocks like [[a .. a+10], [b .. b+10], ...]`.  I had no clue what "by range 10" meant until I read this answer!

Comment: this exactly what i wanted thanks ! sorry for my VERY bad explanation